# How do I install the latest version of GIMP in Luna?

Tags: applications, software-installation, gimp, luna

What is the recommended way to install GIMP 2.8?

The version present in the default elementary Luna repositories is 2.6.

Comment: I'm not sure this is entirely Luna specific. While it is now, as updates are released Freya will fall behind in much the same way.

Comment: @LewisGoddard that's a good point, but that's why both questions and answers can be edited. I'd say let's make them relevant to the current audience, and update later when relevant.

Comment: It currently does apply to Freya users as well, just less so, as there's only 4 patches in it rather than a major release.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Option 1: Upgrade to Freya

The recommended way would be to upgrade to Freya, sooner rather than later. That will get you a whole host of updates on various things, including updating GIMP to [2.8.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gimp).

#### Option 2: Add the Repository

With a little command-line magic, you can indeed upgrade GIMP, and only GIMP, in a way that will keep you up to date in the future. Otto Kesselgulasch's repository will likely upgrade you to the latest release, currently [2.8.14](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp).

The code below adds and auto-confirms the PPA repository, and quietens down the updating a little. That means it may take a while to show progress, and may look like it's stopped, but rest assured it's still working away.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp && 
sudo apt-get update -qq && 
sudo apt-get install gimp
```